# Mapping two classes from same keyPath in RestKit 0.20

Tags: json, ios6, restkit

It  might be a very simple question, but I am not able to map more than one Classes at same keyPath from my JSON data using RestKit. My sample response is:

```
{
  "name":"john"
  "place":"johns"
  "status": true
  "message":"OK"
}
```

Now, the problem is, I want to map name and place to a class named Person and to status and message to another class Status. Can anybody help me, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried adding 2 different response descriptors for the same path pattern and both with nil keypath but different mappings? What did it do?

Comment: I tried putting same keypath for both ResponseDescriptors but its returning one result only, as mapping result dictionary uses keypath as key of objects.

Comment: Can you get the array from the mapping result?

Comment: I am getting only one mapping out of two...

Comment: Cheating, but try making one key path an empty string @""

Comment: Even if it is successful, this way I can have two mappings at most, though I have nearly five different classes to be mapped at same level.

Comment: So I don't think you'll be able to do that directly. I think you'll need to download the data and then run multiple different mappings on it yourself and collate each resulting object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32135/discussion-between-ad-j-and-wain)